# Remove all but one entry in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a huge data set containing a start name, and then several "trips" for each start name. The structure is like this:

[image]

I want to drop basically all trips except one for each start name, so that I end up with a single entry for each start name.

What I tried:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$start",
        "dups": { "$push": "$_id" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    db.events.remove({ "_id": {"$in": doc.dups }});
});

db.test.createIndex({"start":1},{unique:true})
```

This however leads to an error:

> "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test2.test index: start_1 dup key: { : \"A\" }"

Is there a better way to achieve this?

-- Edit:

I solved it by grouping/aggregating the starts first, then putting them into a new collection:

```
var starts = db.test.aggregate(
    {
    $group : {
    _id : "$start",
    duration: { $first: "$duration"}
    }
    }
  );

db.newcollection.insert(starts.toArray());
```

Since I need to keep more than just the `start` field, I also filled in the duration. This way you end up with a single entry for every `start`, with the "first" duration mongoDB determines. This can be adjusted if other (probably static fields) are also needed.

Comment: `"start": { $first: "$start" }` Add this in `$group`. Hope it works.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I am getting the same error upon running the createIndex command.

Comment: Ensure that `db.events.remove` calls complete by the time you call `db.test.createIndex`

Comment: @S.D. Yes I did.

Comment: I found a different way, I aggregated all the starts with the `$first` function, then saved it to a new collection.

Comment: I tried to do the same on my mongodb test collection and it worked even in a large collection. I want to know if you had 2 different collections? If not, the you in aggregate you have db.test and in curser forEach you have db.events, i guess it should be db.test as well right? as you want to check and update the same collection?

Comment: @Blastfreak I updated above what I did.